# Access Puma from outside network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

For over a year I've been able to serve a RoR site using Puma from my local machine. As of yesterday it's no longer available from outside my network. I use DynDns to allow outside users to access via a url vs. an ip address. I have used Dyn's network tool to validate that port 3000 is open to the outside. It is. My router configuration has not changed. Dyn has my correct ip address. (It fails going direct to my ip address also.) I can access the site from 127.0.0.1. The service is started using 'rails s -b 0.0.0.0'. When hit from outside there is no output from Puma. Where can I look to find out what the problem might be?

Output from dig:

```
myMac$ dig mydomain.dyndns-pics.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mydomain.dyndns-pics.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40324
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.dyndns-pics.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.dyndns-pics.com.   60  IN  A   nn.nnn.nn.nn (my ip address)

;; Query time: 159 msec
;; SERVER: 216.146.35.35#53(216.146.35.35)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 25 11:12:35 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the dns server is down?

- use [dig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_(command)) to find out if you dns is really pointing to your ip (could be that the dns server unreachable)
- test requesting your ip directly instead of the dns
- are you listening for ipv4 AND ipv6 connections?

Comment: As stated above, going to the site without using DNS, via the ip address, fails as well.

Comment: can you at least ping the public ip?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the ip address.

Comment: can you run nmap on your public ip and check which open ports it finds?

Comment: you can also run against a specific port: sudo nmap -p port_number remote_host

Answer (score 0):

I recently re-attached my physical ethernet cable to my computer, allowing it to use both wired and wireless connections. My port forwarding rule was routing to my wireless address which had somehow connected to my ceiling fan instead of to my router. All requests for port 3000 were going to my ceiling fan.